# Why use a builder instead of a parameter object?

Tags: c#, builder

Everything I'm able to find concerning the builder pattern only mentions reducing the number of parameters to a constructor.  But if that is all that is needed, why not just create a basic data structure to hold the parameters and pass that?

What is the purpose of a series of methods that essentially does the same thing as setting some variables of a parameter object?

Comment: Say you have a method with 15 parameters, so you create a parameter object to pass with 15 properties. Then, though, you have set all 15 properties on the parameter object, and you would want to use a constructor for that so you don't miss any. So now your parameter object has a constructor with 15 parameters..

Comment: A builder is also very easily extensible

Comment: Also builder can build different types (in same hierarchy) based on different parameters - constructor can't.

Comment: The [SE page on the builder pattern](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/345688/what-are-the-advantages-of-builder-pattern-of-gof) is useful